# MongoDB Atlas database vs MongoDB local, which is best for SaaS in terms of transaction speed (Querying)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, performance, mongodb-atlas

I have developed an automation web tool (SaaS app), right now I'm using mongoDb atlas cloud database with amazon EC2 Xlarge instance with quad core EBS enabled processor and 16GB RAM. Is atlas the best or local mongo if so why?, which will give me a better performance, some serious help here.

Answer (score 27):

**MongoDB**:
you are able to take advantage of this tool since being a non-relational database, it is much easier to build the model of the architecture of the database model. This makes the development time much easier. When working with javascript language, or working with JSON objects and collections, MongoDB makes the connection of services for queries much lighter and optimizes the performance of the applications. Also, you can work, in case you do not know the console commands, with a Desktop database administrator in a graphical way. The learning times really are much faster, which allows a great scalability of the project. In the development department, this optimizes the delivery time with the clients, which makes the projects much more feasible in terms of delivery times.

**PROS:**

- Being a JSON language optimizes the response time of a query, you can directly build a query logic from the same service
- You can install a local, database-based environment rather than the non-relational real-time bases such a firebase does not allow, the local environment is paramount since you can work without relying on the internet.
- Forming collections in Mango is relatively simple, you do not need to know of query to work with it, since it has a simple graphic environment that allows you to manage databases for those who are not experts in console management.

**CONS:**

- MongoDB seems to be one of the most complete tools in its field, I believe that it has all the features that a non-relational database should have.
- Perhaps because it is a relatively new tool there are very few experts in the field of MongoDB.

**To Summarize:**
Mongo DB is better placed in large projects, with great scalability. It also allows you to work quite comfortably with projects based on programming languages such as javascript angular typescript C #. I believe that its performance is much better with the type of technologies that handle very logical, similar terms of programming. If we use languages like java php, for example, it is better to work with relational databases like postgres or mySql.

**MongoDB-atlas**:
my department at the company i work at, is using the MongoDB Atlas cluster that we set up on our own servers. It has reached to a point that it becomes hard to manage and to scale. MongoDB Atlas came to our site with the ability to scale and free of management, which saves a lot of effort for us.

**PROS:**

- No infrastructure on our side. Free of management.
- Easy to scale up and down.
- It has strong authentication and encryption features that make sure that developers don't get lazy and leave out data in the open by leaving their servers unguarded.

**CONS:**

- More granular billing.
- More specific alerting system.
- One of the drawbacks of MongoDB-Atlas is the cost. Hopefully more competition will bring down the costs over time.

**To Summarize:**
I would recommend MongoDB Atlas to every person/company who have a significant need in the NoSQL database and do not want to manage their infrastructure. Using MongoDB Atlas can significantly reduce your management time and cost, which saves valuable resources for other tasks. It also suits a smaller company as MongoDB Atlas scales up and down very quickly.

Hopefully I answered your question, Good Luck!